# Thread Pool : how to spawn a child task from a running task?

Tags: multithreading, threadpool

A simple thread pool with a global shared queue of tasks (functors).

Each worker (thread) will pick up one task from the worker, and execute it. It wont execute the next task, until this one is finished.

Lets imagine a big task that needs to spawn child tasks to produce some data, and then continue with evaluation (for example, to sort a big array before save to disk).

pseudo code of the task code:

```
  do some stuff
  generate a list of child tasks
  threadpool.spawn (child tasks)
  wait until they were executed
  continue my task
```

The problem is that the worker will dead lock, because the task is waiting for the child task, and the thread pool is waiting for the parent task to end, before running the child one.

One idea is to run the child task inside the spawn code:

threadpool.spawn pseudo code:

```
   threadpool.push (tasks)
   while (not all incoming task were executed) 
      t = threadpool.pop()
      t.run()
   return (and continue executing parent task)
```

but, how can I know that all the task were executed , in an efficient way?

Another idea is to split the parent task.. something like this:

task pseudo code:

```
  l = generate a list of child tasks
  threadpool.push ( l , high priority )
  t = create a task to work with generated data
  threadpool.push (t , lo priority )
```

But i found this quite intrusive...

any opinions?

pd. merry christmas!
pd2. edited some bad names

Comment: "The problem is that the worker will dead lock, because the task is waiting for the child task, and the thread pool is waiting for the parent task to end, before running the child one."  - is this an assumption you are making?  There are thread pools that will run the child tasks even if there is a parent task running.  Java Executors can do this.

Comment: What kind of cr*ppy threadpool is this?  A threadpool that requires a thread to complete before running another one isn't a threadpool.

Comment: SB: ofc, but I am coding my own thread pool in c++ , I am asking how to implement that feature by myself

Comment: Hans Passant: sorry if i didnt explained myself... a "worker" is a thread, a task is a "functor" that is executed by each thread. A thread pool will pick up "functors" (tasks) form a queue, and execute them. A thread wont execute the next task in queue until the current one is finished.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a mechanism for the children threads to signal back to the main worker whenever they are done so it can proceed. In Java, [Callable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) tasks submitted to an [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) thread pool respond back with their results as [Future](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)s data structures. Another approach would be to maintain a separate completion signal, something similar to a [CountDownLatch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), which will serve as a common countdown mechanism to be updated every time a thread completes.

Comment: as I said, I am using a thread pool, so, there is a limit in the number of new threads I can create. If my current task blocks waiting for other threads, then it wont never exit. I can find myself with all the threads waiting for child tasks.